# printf not printing unsigned int

Tags: c, printf, unsigned-integer

I'm experiencing the following problem printing unsigned numbers .
Here's whats happening:
When I input a negative value in the array and then try to print it, I can't print the number but other amount is printed.

```
int cant;
int a[30][30];    

int printequation (){
    int x,y;
    for (x=0;x<cant;x++){
        for (y=0;y<cant+1;y++){
            if(y==cant){
                printf(" = %d",a[x][y]);
            }else{
                if (y==0)
                    printf(" %dX%d",a[x][y],(y+1));
                else{
                    if(a[x][y]>0){
                        printf(" + ");
                    }else{
                        printf(" - ");
                    }
                    printf("%uX%d",a[x][y],(y+1)); /*<-----------------here*/
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's an example:

```
input: -2 -2 -2 
output: -2x1 -4294967294x2 = -2  /*here It should print -2 but can't get it*/
```

Comment: `a[x][y]` is not an `unsigned int` but an `int`, you cannot use `u` conversion specifier.

Comment: But I'm using %u the other %d is just for printing another number

Comment: `a[x][y]` and `(y+1)` are both of type `int`, not `unsigned int`. Why are you using `%u`?

Comment: because I need to print just the number not the sign

Comment: The sign is added before in the `if(a[x][y]>0)`

Comment: @user2461687, the field's type code is about the type of the corresponding *argument*.  You are not at liberty to choose randomly.  If you want to print the absolute value of your number, then that's what you should pass as an argument.

Comment: @user2461687 printing a negative `int` as an `unsigned int` won't give you the absolute value. If you want the absolute value use `abs` function.

Comment: oh, now I understand thanks so so much c:

Comment: yes now it works using `abs` funtion

Comment: Be careful: the smallest `int` value, which is `-2147483648` if `int` is 32-bit, has no representable absolute value. (This assumes 2's-complement, which is nearly universal).

Comment: ok thanks so much I'm working with little numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid mixing mis-matched `printf()` format specifiers with argument types. [@ouah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1119701/ouah)

```
//v
int a[30][30];    
...
printf("%uX%d",a[x][y],(y+1));
//       ^
```

To print a signed `int` without its "sign" and work with the entire range of `INT_MIN ... INT_MAX`, a number of approaches:

1. Give up on `INT_MIN` and use `abs()`  [@Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson)

   ```
   printf("%d", abs(x));  // fails for 2's complement INT_MIN
   ```
2. Convert to wider integer.  Fails when wider integer not available - rare.

   ```
   printf("%lld", llabs((long long) x));
   ```
3. Convert to corresponding `unsigned`.  Maybe trouble on rare machines whose `unsigned` positive range is the same as `int` positive range.

   ```
   unsigned u = (unsigned) i;
   if (i < 0) u = UINT_MAX - u;
   printf("%u", u);
   ```
4. Print digits seprately

   ```
   int msdigits = i/10;
   int lsdigit = i%10;
   if (msdigits) {
     printf("%d", abs(msdigits));
   }
   printf("%d", abs(lsdigit));
   ```

Comment: I get this:
`implicit declaration of function 'abs'` and I don't know why, I'm using the abs function outside the printf but I don't know what's happening

Comment: @user2461687 Be sure to add `#include <stdlib.h>`